# Dynamically access dictionary declared in an .ini file

Tags: python, ini

Let this is content of .ini file with more similar dictionaries

```
[section]
cmd_list = {'gamess': "416.gamess/exe/gamess",
            'sjeng': '458.sjeng/exe/sjeng',
            'soplex': '450.soplex/exe/soplex',
            'astar': '473.astar/exe/astar',
           }             
...
```

now in my main file and want to access the dictionary dynamically:

```
for r in 'string'
     cmd_list[r][1] #from .ini
     cmd_list[r][0] #from .ini
    ....
```

how to do that?

Comment: Instead of the `.ini` file, could you just a Python module?

Comment: I've fixed the syntax of the dictionary to be valid Python; please review if those changes are actually valid.

Answer (score 1):

If you parsed the `.ini` file using the [`ConfigParser` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html), the value of `cmd_list` would still be a string containing a Python dict literal; it is not yet a dictionary.

Use the [`ast.literal_eval()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to load it into an actual dictionary:

```
>>> ast.literal_eval('''\
... {'gamess': "416.gamess/exe/gamess",
...             'sjeng': '458.sjeng/exe/sjeng',
...             'soplex': '450.soplex/exe/soplex',
...             'astar': '473.astar/exe/astar',
...            }''')
{'astar': '473.astar/exe/astar', 'sjeng': '458.sjeng/exe/sjeng', 'gamess': '416.gamess/exe/gamess', 'soplex': '450.soplex/exe/soplex'}
>>> cmd_list = _
>>> cmd_list['sjeng']
'458.sjeng/exe/sjeng'
```

If you control the output format, you may want to rethink the strategy though; there are better formats for storing the same information.